# Need a function for delaying without clearing buffer in C language

Tags: c, windows

I use `Sleep()` function under `windows.h` for delaying but it clears the buffer unlike `sleep()` under `unistd.h`.
Is there a function for delaying without clearing the buffer?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<windows.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
  printf("hello"); 
  Sleep(2000); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What buffer are you referring to?

Comment: Which buffer? stdout?

Comment: Buffer of printf() function.

Comment: Why do you want to not flush stdout while sleeping?

Comment: It's very likely that you just need a `'\n'` in your format string or, `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: No, I don't want to clear the buffer.

Comment: This needs to be asked from the Mingw community, or whatever is that compiler used by CodeBlocks. If you use the normal Visual C, with Microsoft's compiler and libraries, Sleep() will not flush anything.

Comment: The code looks like this if it clarifies futher:#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello");
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}

Comment: Edit the code into your question, don't post it as a comment.  How are you running the program?  When run interactively (in a normal console) there won't *be* any buffering in the first place.  (I think Linux defaults to line-buffering, but Microsoft's C runtime defaults to unbuffered.)

Comment: Please explain what output you get, and how this differs from the output you expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are expected `stdout` to be line buffered, so that calling `printf` with no newline does not cause any actual output.  However, the C language standard permits *either* line buffering or no buffering if `stdout` may be an interactive device.  When using the Microsoft C runtime, `stdout` will be unbuffered.

Therefore, the string `hello` is being sent directly to standard output, bypassing the runtime library buffering altogether.  The fact that you're calling Sleep() afterwards has nothing to do with it.

You can use [`setvbuf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86cebhfs.aspx) to explicitly configure `stdout` for full buffering, so that the output will be sent only when you explicitly flush the stream.  Note that the Microsoft C runtime does not support line buffering.

PS: you should also note that to the best of my knowledge there is no requirement for the runtime to provide a buffer of any particular size, or any rule preventing it from flushing the buffer for whatever reason might take its fancy.  If your program *must* not write the output until a later time, I think the only completely safe way to do that is to buffer the data yourself.